# Can iOS apps read the location metadata when allowing access to Photos?

Tags: ios, photos

I am just wondering if by allowing access to Photos, the application has access to read the EXIF metadata (including *where* the photo was taken and stuff like that).

Is that possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the app will have access to the full image data including the EXIF metadata that could contain for example GPS location amongst other things.

On the contrary if you're using a web app and uploading photos to it, the EXIF metadata will [automatically be stripped by Safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16297730) before giving it to the web app.

Comment: Is there any reference to support that? Also, why would Instagram request location access to detect the location instead of using the image metadata?

Comment: Yes, plenty of references exist. Your example is a different situation because the photo library is much different than taking a photo within an app. In order to get the precise location in the latter situation, the app needs GPS access itself.

Comment: They eventually implemented this in the latest versions: even if Instagram doesn't have access to Location services, it will reverse-geocode the location based on the EXIF data of the photo.